# How to hold same requests going to backend in varnish4.0.3 until first one responds

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

My website has below request flow-

AWS CloudFront -> ELB -> Varnish 4.0.3 -> NginX (reverse proxy) -> ELB -> Drupal7

**Working**: Normal flow is working as expected.

**Problem**: When I run load-testing on my site, same request is coming to Drupal server multiple times. e.g. My jMeter bombarded 500 calls to http://website/index.php, ~50% requests hit Drupal server.

**Expectation**: Varnish should hold all the same request, until first responds.

**Observation**: Varnish sending all the same requests to back-end, until response for first request comes

If anyone have implemented such functionality please share

Answer (score 1):

It's weird because Varnish should hold these request as per the doc says : 
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-grace.html

Maybe the first request that comes to the backend ends up in a non cacheable response that get "HIT-FOR-PASS" (subsequent same requests won't hit the cache but rather directly be fetched from the backend).

What is the output from varnishlog, are you sending special header that prevent caching?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! 
My _hit is below-

Comment: sub vcl_hit {
  if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
    # A pure unadultered hit, deliver it
    return (deliver);
  }
  if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
      return (deliver);
    } else {
      return(fetch);
    }
  } else {
      if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
      return (deliver);
    } else {
      return (fetch);
    }
  }
  return (fetch);
}
-------
1. Is it correct
2. How to check requests, which are on hold, while Varnish fetching response from backend

Comment: This is your vcl (varnish config), I would like to see the varnish logs. This is the first thing to look at when troubleshooting varnish. You can see them in real time with `varnishlog` or the history with `varnishlog -d` . See https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/operation-logging.html